# Angular-Material Sidenav cdkScrollable

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, angular-material2, angular-cdk

The Angular Material CDK provides a `Directive` `CdkScrollable`, which allows you to listen to `ScrollEvent`s of a specific container.
I am now trying to access the `CdkScrollable` of the `MatSidenavContent`, which is added by default.
However my `@ViewChild(CdkScrollable)` and `@ContentChild(CdkScrollable)` are always undefined.

My `Component` looks something like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav>Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
    <div>Main content</div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The resulting DOM looks something like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <div class="mat-drawer-backdrop"></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
    <mat-sidenav>Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content cdkScrollable>
          <div>Main content</div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The `mat-sidenav-content` `Component`, which is generated automatically, uses a `CdkScrollable`-Directive, which I need to access.
My question is now:
Is it possible to access that `Directive` and if so, how?

Comment: It's funny that the material docs show this as an example but no matter what i try, ALL NIGHT, it does not work.

Comment: @j_walker_dev I opened an Issue on @angular/material some time ago and the `CdkScrollable` instance is now accessible. See [here](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/8187a0c6896e4e3ea2a6748d90724ac3c880cd60/src/lib/sidenav/sidenav.md#reacting-to-scroll-events-inside-the-sidenav-container)

Comment: Thanks for the help Springbua. I was never able to get the `this.sidenavContainer.scrollable` to be anything other than undefined. I had to instead use only `CdkScrollable`. @ViewChild(MatSidenavContent) still to this day does not work for me trying to get the scroll. It is very weird. Thanks again! I am glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I opened an Issue on @angular/material some time ago and they now expose the `CdkScrollable`-Instance.
To use it, you need to access the `MatSidenavContainer` using `@ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer`. This instance has a public member `scrollable`, which is the `CdkScrollable` instance.
An example can be found [here](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/8187a0c6896e4e3ea2a6748d90724ac3c880cd60/src/lib/sidenav/sidenav.md#reacting-to-scroll-events-inside-the-sidenav-container)

**Edit:**
As the example is not very complete and a few people are having difficulties implementing it, I'll write my own example here:

**HTML**:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
        Sidenav Content
    </mat-sidenav>
    <div>
        Main Content
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavContainer } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer) sidenavContainer: MatSidenavContainer;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.sidenavContainer.scrollable);
    }
}
```

**Important**:

1. Don't use `<mat-sidenav-content>`. This tag is generated automatically and it has the `cdkScrollable` directive attached to it. If you use `<mat-sidenav-content>` in your own template, the `scrollable` will be undefined.
2. Use `AfterViewInit` instead of `OnInit`. As much as I know, `@ViewChild` is resolved in `AfterViewInit`, `OnInit` is probably too early.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Here my [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenavcontainer-scrollable-elementscrolled). I also found this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10884) on @angular/material.

Comment: @stevo I edited my answer. The problem in your example is, that you wirte `<mat-sidenav-content>` yourself. This tag is automatically added by angular material and includes the `cdkScrollable`. In your example this is missing in the final HTML (I have seen that in the developer tools). Also you are using `ngOnInit`, but you should use `AfterViewInit`, if you are working with `ViewChild`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Springrbua! I made a new [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenavcontainer-scrollable-elementscrolled-1) on Stackblitz. Now I can subscribe to `this.sidenavContainer.scrollable.elementScrolled()` but nothing happens.

Comment: Take a look at https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#CdkScrollable The API of CdkScrollable should help. If not, feel free to create a new question and let me know about it.

Comment: #1 under important just saved my mental state. thank you

Answer (score 22):

1. Add to your app module imports: `ScrollDispatchModule`.
2. Add `cdkScrollable` to your `mat-sidenav-content`:

> `<mat-sidenav-content cdkScrollable> </mat-sidenav-content>`

3. In your root component:

a) inject `ScrollDispatcher` from `@angular/cdk/overlay` and subscribe to scrolling:

```
constructor(public scroll: ScrollDispatcher) {

    this.scrollingSubscription = this.scroll
          .scrolled()
          .subscribe((data: CdkScrollable) => {
            this.onWindowScroll(data);
          });
}
```

c) do something when scrolling, e.g. check the offset

```
private onWindowScroll(data: CdkScrollable) {
    const scrollTop = data.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop || 0;
    if (this.lastOffset > scrollTop) {
      // console.log('Show toolbar');
    } else if (scrollTop < 10) {
      // console.log('Show toolbar');
    } else if (scrollTop > 100) {
      // console.log('Hide toolbar');
    }

    this.lastOffset = scrollTop;
  }
```

Documentation: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api

**Update Angular 9 :**

Use `import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling'`, `ScrollDispatchModule` is deprecated

Comment: I think you can also do it like this? const scrollable = this.scrollDispatcher.getAncestorScrollContainers(this.elementRef)[0]; console.log(scrollable.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop);

Comment: Could you explain how to use 'elementScrolled' method of 'CdkScrollable' directive in place of scroll.scrolled?

Comment: `data` is always `undefined`. Why?

Comment: FYI - `ScrollDispatchModule` has been renamed to `ScrollingModule`

Comment: @smartmouse this could help http://programmersought.com/article/3361447407/;jsessionid=47E5478BE7087A1887279677D8663327

Comment: Yes the data is undefined for me too. @smartmouse did u find any resolution to it ?