# using CdkScrollable to scroll up on NavigationEnd in angular material2

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material2

I would like to scroll to top on NavigationEnd.

Previously I did like this:

```
  this.router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((event) => {
    // scroll to top on navigation
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  });
```

And that worked but now we have changed the html/css layout so we would like to rely on the CdkScrollable directive but I can't get the elementRef?

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812763/1288587

Answer (score 3):

In component 
`@ViewChildren(CdkScrollable) cdkScrollable;`

In function scrollToEnd
`this.cdkScrollable.first.scrollTo({bottom: 0});`