# ElementScrolled Event is not being fired with CdkScrollable and mat-side-nav

Tags: scroll, angular-material, observable, angular10, mat-sidenav

I have the following DOM Configuration

```
<div class="sticky-nav-wrapper">
    <app-header (notificationClick)="notificationData=$event; sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
</div>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over">
        <app-notifications [notificationData]="notificationData" [opened]="sidenav.opened" (notificationItemClick)="sidenav.close()"></app-notifications>
    </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

In my `app-notification` component which is inside mat-sidenav, I want to listen to the scroll. Following is my template for app-notification

```
<div class="class-notification-container" cdkScrollable>
    <div *ngIf="notifications && notifications.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let item of notifications">
            <div class="class-notification" [ngClass]="{'class-notification-new': item.localStatus === 'new','class-notification-old': item.localStatus === 'seen'}" (click)="onNotificationClick(item)">
                <app-avatar [imageId]="item?.fromUser?.id"></app-avatar>
            </div>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my app-notification.ts:

```
@ViewChild(CdkScrollable) notificationContainer: CdkScrollable;
```

and

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.notificationContainer.elementScrolled()
      .subscribe((scrollPosition) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          if (!this.endOfNotifications) {
            this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
            this.getNotifications();
          }
        });
      }, (error) => {});
  }
```

However, this subscription is never invoked, no matter how much I scroll inside the mat-side-nav. The docs says that the CdkScrollable directive emits an observable on host elemnet scroll.

> Returns observable that emits when a scroll event is fired on the host
> element.

The other alternative is to listen to the `scrollDispatcher`. The issue however is scrolldispatcher is sending events on window scroll and not specifically on side-nav scroll.

I seem to be doing everything OK as per the doc. Can someone please suggest where the things are going wrong. I specifically want to listen to the scroll of my component within the side-nav i.e. `app-notification` component. Also I do not want to listen to the window scroll or to say the `mat-side-nav-content` scroll.

Answer (score 0):

It may be you're listening on too high of a parent.

Have you tried listening on the div with the *ngFor ?

```
<div >
    <div *ngIf="notifications && notifications.length > 0">
        <div class="class-notification-container" cdkScrollable *ngFor="let item of notifications">
            <div class="class-notification" [ngClass]="{'class-notification-new': item.localStatus === 'new','class-notification-old': item.localStatus === 'seen'}" (click)="onNotificationClick(item)">
                <app-avatar [imageId]="item?.fromUser?.id"></app-avatar>
            </div>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528852/angular-material-sidenav-cdkscrollable